# Extending login function from django.contrib.auth.views (Django project)

Tags: django, django-views, django-contrib

**BACKGROUND:**

I'm using the versatile [django-brake](https://github.com/gmcquillan/django-brake) for rate limiting in my Django app. I now need to configure it to limit brute force login attempts in my app too.

The way to do that is to decorate the `login` view with the decorator `ratelimit(field='username')` and adding `was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)` inside the view. `was_limited` is `True` if the same username (OR IP) is used >5 times/min. One can then redirect offending users, etc.

**SCENARIO:**

Currently, I'm using the `login` function in `django.contrib.auth.views`. I can decorate this function in my urls.py. But I can't include `was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)` inside the function that way. And that is mission critical, since only once that flag is `True` can I take action against the offending user.

**QUESTION:**

So what's the best way for me to decorate and extend this function to include the above functionality? Do I need to override the whole thing, and if so, how? Please advise. I can directly write the required code in `django.contrib.auth.views`, but that's a hack.

Being a beginner, I'm trying to come up with the best way to deal with a situation like this. An illustrative example would be nice.

---

For reference, I'm including `django.contrib.auth.views.login` below:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the work is already done in the decorator, by the looks of things. The examples show adding `was_limited` if you want to do something extra inside the view to say that requests were previously limited, but there's certainly no need to do so and it won't have any effect on the functionality.

Comment: Ah no. Unless I can access `was_limited` flag, I can't actually redirect or take some kind of action against the offending user. The flag turns to `True` when the rate limit is reached.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and its working. See the reference from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/

```
def my_login(request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: Please do not use this.  Besides the fact that the POST data is not being cleaned, exposing a security vulnerability, you should be passing a Django Form to the template to collect and validate the login information.

If you just 'plug' this into your existing code, chances are it won't work at all -- you won't even get the username and password boxes.

Besides all that, the nesting in the example is terrible and there is no mention of the was_limited flag which was the entire point.

I know this is old, but I just wanted to say this in case someone else comes along and tries it.